# Passing a value in MongoDB aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Lets say I have the following partial document

```
{ 
  "groups": [
  {
    "color": "Red",
    "key": 1,
  },
  {
    "color": "Blue",
    "key": 2,
  },
  {
    "color": "Yellow",
    "key": 3,
  },
  "members": [
  {
    "name": "Deen",
    "groupKey": 1,
  },
  {
    "name": "Joe",
    "groupKey": 2,
  },
  {
    "name": "Michel",
    "groupKey": 1,
  },
  {
    "name": "Simon",
    "groupKey": 3,
  },
 ]
}
```

I would like to get the matching members according to the group color. For example, for Red I'll get Deen and Michel, for Blue I'll get Joe and for Yellow I'll get Simon.

Is that possiable to do in one aggregation?
I need to get the group key by querying its color and from there get the members by querying there groupKey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation in 3.4.

You can locate the index of matching color in groups array and output the matching group followed by `$filter` to filter all the members for matching "groupKey".

Note this solution works when you always find a matching color or else the `$indexOfArray` returns -1 and you will not get expected results. To account for this you can add a `$cond` operator to check the index before getting the group doc.

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {"$addFields":{
    "members":{
      "$let":{
        "vars":{
          "group":{
            "$arrayElemAt":["$groups",{"$indexOfArray":["$groups.color","Red"]}]
          }
        },
        "in":{
          "$filter":{"input":"$members","cond":{"$eq":["$$this.groupKey","$$group.key"]}}
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```